# Electron + webpack + HMR net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: webpack, electron, webpack-hmr

### Context

I try to make a small app using Electron / Webpack / React. I'm at the beginning of my project - the dev setup. So forget React for now.

### Problem

I can't make the webpack hot reload working with electron. It is triggering, but no changes are made.

### Details

I get this error (from the devTools console) when hot reload is triggering : `GET file:///.../static/19a4692a1230e5770d9e.hot-update.json net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. I got this error only in Electron, but from a simple web page (Chrome) hot reload works well with no errors. [Here my repo git](https://github.com/soywod/stack-overflood). To reproduce, launch `yarn watch` and `yarn start` in two consoles and try to modify `src/app.js`.

Thx for you help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to specify in the output part of my webpack config. I set the key `publicPath` with the value `http://localhost:8080/` and it worked.